# remove html node from htmldocument :HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, collections, iteration, html-agility-pack, dom

In my code, I want to remove the img tag which doesn't have src value.
    I am using **HTMLAgilitypack's HtmlDocument** object.
    I am finding the img which doesn't have src value and trying to remove it.. but it     gives me error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
    Can anyone help me for this?
    The code which I have used is:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes())
{
    if (node.Name.ToLower() == "img")
    {                            
           string src = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(src))
           {
               node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, false);    
           }
   }
   else
   {
             ..........// i am performing other operations on document
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I have done is:

```
    List<string> xpaths = new List<string>();
    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes())
    {
                        if (node.Name.ToLower() == "img")
                        {
                            string src = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(src))
                            {
                                xpaths.Add(node.XPath);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
    }

    foreach (string xpath in xpaths)
    {
            doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).Remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 28):

It seems you're modifying the collection during the enumeration by using `HtmlNode.RemoveChild` method.

To fix this you need is to copy your nodes to a separate list/array by calling e.g. [`Enumerable.ToList<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) or [`Enumerable.ToArray<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx).

```
var nodesToRemove = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//img[not(string-length(normalize-space(@src)))]")
    .ToList();

foreach (var node in nodesToRemove)
    node.Remove();
```

If I'm right, the problem will disappear.

Comment: @Piya, glad to hear that. But I think by using one xpath expression is easier to make your code more readable (just select all the nodes to remove with one expression).

Answer (score 4):

```
var emptyImages = doc.DocumentNode
 .Descendants("img")
 .Where(x => x.Attributes["src"] == null || x.Attributes["src"].Value == String.Empty)
 .Select(x => x.XPath)
 .ToList(); 

emptyImages.ForEach(xpath => { 
      var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
      if (node != null) { node.Remove(); }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var emptyElements = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("a")
    .Where(x => x.Attributes["src"] == null || x.Attributes["src"].Value == String.Empty)
    .ToList();

emptyElements.ForEach(node => {
    if (node != null){ node.Remove();}
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.