# Remove "img" and "a" tags from node.InnerHtml

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to extract only text from my html

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
doc.LoadHtml(inputHTml);

foreach (var node in Doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.Name == "strong" || node.Name == "#text" 
        || node.Name == "br" || node.Name == "div" 
        || node.Name == "p" || node.Name != "img")
    {
        sb.Append(node.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```

now in my node.InnerHtml is this html:

1.

```
<br><div>text</div><div>, text</div><div>text<br>
<img src="http://example.com/55.jpg" alt="" title="" height="100">
<img src="http://example.com/45.jpg" alt="text" title="text" height="100"></div>
```

2.

```
text&nbsp;text&nbsp;text.&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
 href="/content/essie-classics">text</a><br>
  <img> src="" alt="" title="" height="100"><img
 src="http://example.com/img_8862.jpg"
 alt="" title="" height="100">
```

how to remove img and a tags?

img tag not have the close tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand what point no.2 means. But if you want to remove all `<img>` element from a `HtmlNode`, you can try this way :

```
var imgs = node.SelectNodes("//img");
foreach (var img in imgs)
{
    img.Remove();
}
```

`Remove()` function will remove `HtmlNode` from it's parent. This works fine for me to remove `<img>` elements, even without closing tag.

**UPDATE :**

You can use this XPath expression to select all `<img>` and `<a>` elements in single query :

```
node.SelectNodes("//*[self::img or self::a]");
```

then you can iterate through result set once to remove each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [remove html node(img) from htmldocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106280/remove-html-node-from-htmldocument-htmlagilitypack)  sample.
you can also do like that:

```
       var sb = new StringBuilder();
doc.LoadHtml(inputHTml);

        foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.Name != "img" && node.Name!="a")
        {
            sb.Append(node.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
```