# How to get text from html nodes and solve character encoding issue?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get innertext in this site http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/yazarlar/22933964.asp

with htmlagilitypack. 
html structure is

```
<div class="detailText">
<span class="yzrArticleDate">30 Mart 2014</span>
<h1 class="yazarArticleTitle">31 Mart sabahı için acil ihtiyaç listesi</h1>
<p></p><p><p  >Akıl.<br  />Sağduyu.<br  />Barış.<br  />
Özgürlük.<br  />Kardeşlik.<br  />Vicdan.<br  />Huzur.............
```

and my current code

```
string htmlContent = getsource(s);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
var noa =document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//div[@class='detailText']").InnerText;
```

problem is it gets with the heading and date. I mean with "30 Mart 2014" and "31 Mart sabahı için acil ihtiyaç listesi".

I want  the part which begins with

```
<*p><*/p><*p><p*  >Akıl.<*br "
```

I tried different variation

```
var noa =document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//div[@class='detailText']").InnerHtml;     
var noa = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//div[@class='detailText']").NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
var noa = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//div[@class='detailText']").LastSibling.InnerText;
```

my second question ; if I manage to text this text I ll be faced a character encoding problem, how can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to remove nodes you don't want and than get `InnerHtml`/`InnerText` as covered in [remove html node from htmldocument :HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106280/remove-html-node-from-htmldocument-htmlagilitypack).

```
var noa =document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("*//div[@class='detailText']")
noa.RemoveChild(noa.SelectSingleNode("span")); 
// remove the rest too...
var result = noa.InnerText;
```

There should be no encoding problem unless site reports invalid encoding as C# strings are Unicode (UTF16).

Comment: sadly there is. http://i.imgur.com/ZzuTr11.png   . is it about the method that I try to get page source ? http://i.imgur.com/JzllHsU.png